# Java: String.format not working 'f != [F'

Tags: java, formatting

I tried using `String.format` to format some floats.

If I do this:

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%5.2f %5.2f", 2.35792f, 8.9479f));
    }
}
```

Then it seems to work and prints out  `2.36  8.95`.

However, if I extract this to a method:

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatFloats(2.35792f, 8.9479f));
    }

    private static String formatFloats(float...fs) {
        StringBuilder formatStr = new StringBuilder();
        for (float v: fs) {
            formatStr.append("%5.2f ");
        }
        return String.format(formatStr.toString().trim(), fs);
    }
}
```

then it raises an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != [F
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2898)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:3292)
    at demo.vec3.TestClass.formatFloats(TestClass.java:12)
    at demo.vec3.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:4)
```

I tried to print `formatStr.toString().trim()`, but it does output `%5.2f %5.2f`.

The error message is cryptic, and I don't understand what it means at all. I believe it has something to do with how I am using `float...fs`.

(I am using Eclipse IDE to write and run my application.)

---

Remark: It turns out that if I change my function code slightly to this:

```java
private static String formatFloats(Object...fs) {
    StringBuilder formatStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object v: fs) {
        formatStr.append("%5.2f ");
    }
    return String.format(formatStr.toString().trim(), fs);
}
```

then it works, outputting  `2.36  8.95` again.

Comment: In `[f` the `[` means *one dimensional array* and `f` stands for `float`. In other words `[f` represents `float[]`. The `%5.2f` expects single `float` but received `float[]` instead which caused exception. Why it received whole array? Because in `format(pattenr, Object... values)` the varargs `Object... values` represent `Object[]`, but `float[]` is not its subtype (the `Float[]` would be, but Java doesn't automatically convert float[] to Float[]). In other words `Object... values` considers `float[]` as *single* element (single Object).

Comment: "*why this question was downvoted*" only the down-voter knows. But people are not obligated to explain their votes so I doubt you will get his response. Also he may no longer read this question - usually people cast their votes and move on to next question - so he probably is not aware of your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct.  When you pass in a `float[]`, Java thinks you are trying to print *one argument*, a `float[]`, rather than all the individual float elements of the array.  Only an `Object[]` is compatible with the varargs used by `String.format`, allowing each individual float to be interpreted as a separate `format` argument.

Note that `Float[]` will also work, since `Float[]` can be upcast to `Object[]`, but `float[]` cannot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your first rendition of the `formatFloats()` method, you just need to actually do the formatting within the StringBuilder append, for example:

```
private static String formatFloats(float... fs) {
    StringBuilder formatStr = new StringBuilder("");
    for (float v: fs) {
        formatStr.append(String.format("%-6.2f ", v));
    }
    return formatStr.toString();
}
```